# How to sign a cookie on a rails API based on a parameter sent by a react front end app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, cookies

So, as the question says, i want to sign a cookie from my server (Rails API), based on a parameter that i send from a react application, i already tested that the parameter is being successfully received on the back end.

The weird think is that if i send exactly the same parameter from one of my Rails application views, it signs the cookie correctly.

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      skip_before_action :ensure_authenticated_user, only: %i( new create )
      # Here is where the method where i receive the user_id param from my react app via post request 
      def create
        # authenticate_user method is defined on my application controller
        authenticate_user(params[:user_id])
      end

    end
```

And here in my application controller is where i define the authenticate_user method

```
require "application_responder"

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  self.responder = ApplicationResponder
  respond_to :html
  before_action :ensure_authenticated_user

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token


  def ensure_authenticated_user
    authenticate_user(cookies.signed[:user_id]) || redirect_to(new_session_url)
  end

  # authenticate_user method definition
  def authenticate_user(user_id)
    if authenticated_user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      puts 'autenticating: ' + authenticated_user.name
      cookies.signed[:user_id] ||= user_id
      @current_user = authenticated_user
    end
  end

  def unauthenticate_user
    ActionCable.server.disconnect(current_user: @current_user)
    @current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
  end
end
```

Thanks a lot for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send de AJAX request with credentials. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials.

Depending on the HTTP library you are using the way of configuring that field can vary. For example, if you are using axios:

```
axios("http://example.com/api/things/", {
  method: "post",
  data: someJsonData,
  withCredentials: true
})
```

With fetch:

```
fetch('/api/v2/user/me', {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    'Accept':  'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Cache': 'no-cache'
  },
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})
```